# Windows web server for in-house apps?

Tags: windows, web, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hi,

Ms site for Windows Web Server 2008 R2 states that it's only licensed to server internet-facing web apps.

What does that mean for in-house applications? That I am allowed to host B2B/C site on those, but not my internal web based ERP, for example?

Thanks

Comment: The Internet is everywhere, so no matter where you put the server, it's technically "facing the Internet," and your in-house clients just happen to be in the way.

Comment: using this kind of wordplay might sound good but it does not change the fact that you would not be covered for a server setup solely for internal use

Comment: I forgot to include the :) at the end of my comment.

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Your application has to be internet facing. THat does not mean everyone can have access - so putting it out, SSL, password - is totally ok. But it has to be accessible (HTTP request) from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> What does that mean for in-house
>   applications?

It means they are not covered by a web license. This is not a disadvantage, though. Inhouse normal licensing applies, and normally you don't need CALs *because people already have them*.

The whole main problem with web is to avoid the "I need a lot of CALs for visitors from the internet" thing. It is a cheap small server which vocers the special issues of the internet (high number of visitors). MS standard licensing breaks apart there financially AND practically.

Internally, just don't use web. Use / reuse a standard (chance is some are lying around).