# Microsoft Windows Web Server 2008 Licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Related to [Windows web server for in-house apps?](https://serverfault.com/q/195699/59025), but with a twist.

Is a W2K8 Web Server licence acceptable for a web-based application with the following features:

- Externally accessed by users with application-level username/password authentication and impersonation.
- Internally accessed by users with domain accounts, using integration authentication but also configured to use impersonation.
- Connecting to a separate SQL Server 2008 cluster with processer licences. No other access to SQL apart from administration.
- Load balanced with WLBS over two nodes.

Specific questions:

1. Do I need user CALs for the internal users?
2. Do I need user or device CALs for the Windows installs on the database servers? Or an external connector license? Or does impersonation cover this (single domain account accessing the database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No the Web server does not need CALs for anyone. But the Domain Controller(s) need CALs for authenticating your internal users.
2. Your SQL server, if licensed per processor does not need SQL CALs at all. The Windows Server software it runs on must be licensed and have CALs for any users that will login to the the server as usual (SQL users who auth through AD would require CALs on the DC as in #1).

Comment: Server instances that run SQL Server can have External Connector License instead of user CALs for external users.